# The inverse stereographic projection is a conformal map

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-topology, conformal-geometry, stereographic-projections

How can one establish that the inverse stereographic projection $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ given by
$$
f(x,y):= \frac{(2x,2y,x^2+y^2-1)}{x^2+y^2+1}
$$
is a conformal (angle-preserving) map?

I wanted to show by a direct calculation that this map preserves angles. I considered two vectors $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb R^2$ as well as two vectors $f(x_1,y_1),f(x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb R^3$.

If I denote $\theta$ to be the angle between $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ and $f(\theta)$ to be the angle between $f(x_1,y_1),f(x_2,y_2)$, then I want to establish $f(\theta)=\theta$.

First, I observe that $f(x,y)$ has unit magnitude:
\begin{align*}
\|f(x,y)\| &= \frac{\sqrt{(2x)^2+(2y)^2+(x^2+y^2-1)^2}}{x^2+y^2+1} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{4(x^2+y^2)+((x^2+y^2)^2-2(x^2+y^2)+1)}}{x^2+y^2+1} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^2+2(x^2+y^2)+1}}{x^2+y^2+1} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}}{x^2+y^2+1} \\
&= 1,
\end{align*}
confirming that the inverse stereographic projection maps the plane back to the unit sphere except the north and south poles.

Well, now I have
\begin{align*}
\cos f(\theta) &= \frac{f(x_1,y_1)\cdot f(x_2,y_2)}{\|f(x_1,y_1)\|\|f(x_2,y_2)\|} \\
&= \frac{(2x_1,2y_1,x_1^2+y_1^2-1) \cdot(2x_2,2y_2,x_2^2+y_2^2-1)}{1 \cdot 1} \\
&= \frac{(2x_1)(2x_2)+(2y_1)(2y_2)+(x_1^2+y_1^2-1)(x_2^2+y_2^2-1)}{(x_1^2+y_1^2+1)(x_2^2+y_2^2+1)}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\cos\theta &= \frac{(x_1,y_1)\cdot (x_2,y_2)}{\|(x_1,y_1)\|\|(x_2,y_2)\|} \\
&= \frac{x_1x_2+y_1y_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}}.
\end{align*}
However, I am stuck on how to get my expressions of $\cos \theta$ and of $\cos f(\theta)$ to equal.

Comment: You need to compute the angle between *tangent vectors* to curves in the plane and correspondingly in the sphere, not the position vectors themselves. (In the plane you can use lines, but you need to find the tangent vectors to the images of those lines at the appropriate point of the sphere.) This argument can be made purely geometrically by observing that lines in the plane map to circles on the sphere and then doing a bit of geometry.

Comment: Would I need to find a general expression of a vector that is tangent to the unit sphere? I can only think of easy examples such as (0,1,0),(0,0,1) which are vectors in R3 that are tangent to the unit sphere at (1,0,0), with the angle between them being $\frac{\pi}2$.

Comment: You need to differentiate the map $f$ at an arbitrary point in directions $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: Since I am dealing with $f(x,y)$ as a vector in $\mathbb R^3$, is it an option for me to parameterize $x,y,z$ in $t \in \mathbb R$ in two different ways (to represent the directions $v_1$ and $v_2$)? Then I might be able to write $f(x,y)$ somehow as $\bf{r}_1(t),\bf{r}_2(t)$ and differentiate both of them in $t$. Then I would find the angle between the two vectors $\bf{r}_1'(t),\bf{r}_2'(t)$.

Comment: Yes, that’s the same as what I said. :)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a tangent vector when written as a directional derivative concerns a parameterized vector at $t=0$:  $$(D_{v} f)(x) ~ \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} ~
  \left. \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}{t}} [f(x + t v)] \right|_{t = 0}).$$ So should I really find the angle $f(\theta)$ between the two vectors $\mathbf r_1'(0),\mathbf r_2'(0)$ -- rather than $\mathbf r_1'(t),\mathbf r_2'(t)$ in general -- to compare with the angle $\theta$ between $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$? In my own calculations right now, I can only get my angles $\theta,f(\theta)$ to be the same at $t=0$.

Comment: I'm still confused a little bit with my intuition here because something is also telling me that maybe I should compute the angle $f(\theta)$ for $\mathbf r_1'(t),\mathbf r_2'(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$ in order to address all parameterized points $(x(t),y(t)) \in \mathbb R^2$, at least after applying transformations such as translation, rotation, dilation, inversion, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Parametrizing curves and taking derivatives will work, but I prefer to work directly with the tangent spaces. In this case, the tangent space of your domain, which is $\mathbb{R}^2$, it actually $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself. If you want to show that your map $f$ is conformal, you need to show that for vectors $u$ and $v$ in the tangent space of $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}$ there is a number $\lambda(x,y)$ so that $u\cdot v=\lambda(x,y) df_{(x,y)}(u)\cdot df_{(x,y)}(v)$. The notation here is that $df_{(x,y)}$ is the Jacobian of $f$ evaluated at $(x,y)$. Computing the Jacobian is not so hard: $$df_{(x,y)}=\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}\begin{bmatrix}
2(y^2-x^2+1)& -4xy\\
-4xy & 2(x^2-y^2+1) \\
-4x& -4y\end{bmatrix}$$
Disregard the coefficient in front of this matrix for now and label the entries $f_{i,x}$ and $f_{i,y}$. If $u=(u_1,u_2)$ and $v=(v_1,v_2)$, then evaluating $df_{(x,y)}$ on these vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ gives two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which we can write compactly as
$$df_{(x,y)}(u)=\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}(f_{i,x}u_1+f_{i,y}u_2)_{i=1}^3\quad \quad df_{(x,y)}(v)=\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}(f_{i,x}v_1+f_{i,y}v_2)_{i=1}^3$$
The dot product of these vectors is therefore the sum of the componentwise products
\begin{align}df_{(x,y)}(u)\cdot df_{(x,y)}(v)&=\left[\sum_{i=1}^3 f_{i,x}^2u_1v_1+f_{i,x}f_{i,y}(u_1v_2+u_2v_1)+f_{i,y}^2u_2v_2\right]\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+1)^4}
\end{align}
But for clarity we will rearrange as
$$\left[u_1v_1\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 f_{i,x}^2\right)+u_2v_2\left(\sum_{i=1}^3f_{i,y}^2\right)+(u_1v_2+u_2v_1)\sum_{i=1}^3 f_{i,x}f_{i,y}\right]\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+1)^4}$$
It takes some elbow grease, but you can show that $\sum_{i=1}^3 f_{i,x}^2=\sum_{i=1}^3 f_{i,y}^2=4(x^2+y^2+1)^2$ and also that $\sum_{i=1}^3 f_{i,x}f_{i,y}=0$. I will leave the former to you, for the latter:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^3 f_{i,x}f_{i,y}&=2(y^2-x^2+1)(-4xy)+(-4xy)2(x^2-y^2+1)+(-4x)(-4y)\\
&=(-8xy)\left[y^2-x^2+1+x^2-y^2+1\right]+16xy\\
&=-16xy+16xy=0
\end{align}
In conclusion, we see that $df_{(x,y)}(u)\cdot df_{(x,y)}(v)=\frac{4(u\cdot v)}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}$. In particular, letting $\lambda(x,y)=\frac{4}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}$, we see that $f$ is a conformal map. Note that the function $\lambda(x,y)$ is the *stretching factor*. Near the origin, thinking about the projection itself, we expect little to no stretching. Indeed, we see that near the origin $f$ is nearly the identity, only scaling by $4$. On the other hand, when $(x,y)$ is very far away from the origin, making $x^2+y^2$ large, $\lambda(x,y)$ is very small. This is because the projection is trying to squeeze all of these far away points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ near the north pole of $S^2$.